# Usage of Vてかなわない

Tags: grammar

Could somebody help me figuring out in what way Vてかなわない is different from Vしょうがない　or Vてたまらない? It would be helpful if somebody could also provide me some examples too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried searching about Learn JLPT N1 Grammar: てかなわない (te kanawanai)

Answer (score 1):

1. 〜てかなわない < 敵う no match/comparable
2. 〜てしかたない < 仕方がない no choice
3. 〜てたまらない < たまらない unbearable

The given situations on #1 is objective. #2 and #3 has almost no difference and subjective, in general, it's up to the person who thinks it is. Examples,

したくて敵わない connotes 'I can't overcome without doing so', often  used in Kansai dialect.
例)　暑くて敵わない - too hot to survive
例)　重くて運べない - too heavy to carry

したくて仕方がない connotes 'I can't live without doing so'.
例)　嬉しくて仕方ない - beside oneself with joy
例)　面倒でしょうがない - too reluctant to do it

したくてたまらない connotes 'I can't help/control myself without doing so', the most emotional expression among these.
例)　珈琲が飲みたくてたまらない - thirst for a cup of coffee
例)　話したくてたまらない - hardly keep it in my mind, want to share it

Comment: What does the < notation mean?

Comment: `>` is an arrow, means 'from-to', 'made of' or 'related to'. A > B means B is made of A. I do not remember which English dictionary uses this mark to show the etymology, pocket version of Dutch English or French English, Pocket OALD. But Japanese people like this arrow mark a lot.

Comment: Thanks. An arrow to me is → /←or ->/<-, when I see >/< alone, I read “greater/less than” so there was a bit of dissonance here.

Comment: I do understand, if my mother tongue is European, then I thought < is used for math. or shell scripts. In 1990s, we developed a lot of Emojis by text based chat.  ...φ(◎◎ﾍ) ﾎｫﾎｫ. (taking notes, that's interesting) one liner comic. *A man with eye glasses writing down.*